# Has Anyone Integrated Clover as a Payment Processor?

Tags: payment-processor, payment

We have a new client, an art gallery, that uses Clover for their merchant processing in the gallery. They'd like to simplify things by changing from PayPal as the CiviCRM payment processor to Clover.

Has anyone done this and were you able to do this with an existing payment processor within CiviCRM or did it require custom coding.

Thank you.